# How to delete a particular row in a Mysql table by order of row number?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, delete-row

Here am working with a content library in angular where a delete function call API to delete an image file with index (i) from DB where the file path stored. But the problem is DB has an id that is auto-incremented and stated as the primary key. **how can I delete a particular row for eg row with ID 17 by using index i= 4?**

The DB I want to delete a particular row is the following one.

```
mysql> select * from ezign.t_content_library;
+----+---------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| id | content_name                                | content_path                                                | created_time  |
+----+---------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| 14 | gayathri-sri-ptbKY_b1ROc-unsplash.jpg       | /assets/content/gayathri-sri-ptbKY_b1ROc-unsplash.jpg       | 1597082730561 |
| 15 | nathan-anderson-UhagOo7IOyc-unsplash.jpg    | /assets/content/nathan-anderson-UhagOo7IOyc-unsplash.jpg    | 1597131503584 |
| 16 | melnychuk-nataliya-8J6uuvsdj-4-unsplash.jpg | /assets/content/melnychuk-nataliya-8J6uuvsdj-4-unsplash.jpg | 1597141241146 |
| 17 | jo-jo-mPM-x0zPhok-unsplash.jpg              | /assets/content/jo-jo-mPM-x0zPhok-unsplash.jpg              | 1597141406728 |
+----+---------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

***Is there is any code like
DELETE FROM t_content_library WHERE ..............?***

Comment: take a look at mysql ROW_NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and `join`:

```
delete cl
    from ezign.t_content_library cl join
         (select cl.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
          from ezign.t_content_library cl
         ) cl2
         on cl2.id = cl.id
    where cl2.seqnum = 4;
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
delete cl
    from ezign.t_content_library cl join
         (select cl.*
          from ezign.t_content_library cl
          order by id
          limit 1 offset 3  -- 3 = 4 - 1
         ) cl2
         on cl2.id = cl.id;
```

Unfortunately, `DELETE` allows `LIMIT` but not with an `OFFSET`, so I think a `JOIN` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `id` that you want to delete with this query:

```
select id 
from t_content_library 
order by id limit 3, 1
```

The number `3` after `LIMIT` means that 3 rows will be skipped and the number `1` means that 1 row after the 3 skipped rows will be returned, thus the `id` of the 4th row will be returned.

You can use the above query in the `DELETE` statement like this:

```
delete
from t_content_library
where id = (select id from (select id from t_content_library order by id limit 3, 1) t);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/24kfvs1Si8C9uVP7N6Q35r/0).
Results:

```
| id  | content_name                                | content_path                                                | created_time  |
| --- | ------------------------------------------- | ----------------------------------------------------------- | ------------- |
| 14  | gayathri-sri-ptbKY_b1ROc-unsplash.jpg       | /assets/content/gayathri-sri-ptbKY_b1ROc-unsplash.jpg       | 1597082730561 |
| 15  | nathan-anderson-UhagOo7IOyc-unsplash.jpg    | /assets/content/nathan-anderson-UhagOo7IOyc-unsplash.jpg    | 1597131503584 |
| 16  | melnychuk-nataliya-8J6uuvsdj-4-unsplash.jpg | /assets/content/melnychuk-nataliya-8J6uuvsdj-4-unsplash.jpg | 1597141241146 |
```